# Using SignalR with AngularJS, how to write unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, knockout.js, signalr

I currently have an app that get data using SignalR and binds to the DOM using Knockout. The app has grown and Knockout is getting pretty complex and bloated, so I'm switching to AngularJS for front-end binding.

However, the Angular tutorials I'm following all seem to get data from the server using $http GET. I really like getting data using SignalR because I can return just pure objects, or Lists or Dictionaries from the server-side code and get it to the client without having to stringify or deserialise.

Implementing SignalR client methods is probably simple, but how do I write the unit tests to test Angular controller methods that require SignalR hub connection?

Comment: What you describe is common, an app starts out, grows over time and the technical debt built into it begin to drag.  This is where refactoring comes in, in your case a radical switch to angular.  Once a person has refactored things enough they begin to learn "Separation of concerns".  I've found that anytime any method or function has more than about 10 lines of code, it may be trying to do too much.  Each method or function should only do one thing.  Also remember that containment is far superior to big long inheritance chains.

Answer (score 0):

Its not knockouts fault that your application is complex and bloated, you can get there with Angular too, just saying. Also there is no difference with SignalR is also needs to deserialize JSON. I do not see the reason to use SignalR if you will not push state from server to client, look into WebAPI

Mocking external calls is very easy in a dynamic languange

just do (Pseudo code)

```
foo.functionname = function(params) {
   assert(1, params, "It should call server with params = 1");
}
```

Comment: But with SignalR I don't have to serialise and deserialise my objects, I just return the object in the Hub class and it's passed over fine to my client-side method. That's not the case with a standard GET request.

Comment: You can use jQuery or other library to do the same, there is no reason to use SignalR if you just want that feature. SignalR is a pub/sub framework for pushing messages from server directly to the clients